# Why a blockchain network slows down as the block size reaches its limit?

Tags: blockchain

I have learned that as the blockchain's block is reaching the limit the network slows down.

Is this because the block is reaching its limit or because the bigger the block the more burden is put on the network.

I understand that the limit was set to prevent a denial of service attack, because somebody could create a really big block that could take the network down.

Now, how exactly a bigger block puts more burden on the newtwork?

The way I understand it is that when somebody solves the puzzle that block is broadcast to other nodes,  all the other nodes have to do is verify that the puzzle is solve and incorporate that block to the ledger.

Is the workload increased in verifying that a broadcast node has indeed a solved puzzle or in incorporating a bigger block into the ledger.

Why would verifying a bigger block is more burdensome, and what the verification consists of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this because the block is reaching its limit or because the bigger the block the more burden is put on the network.

It is because all full nodes have to download, verify, and relay the block.

It is trivial to create a valid block that has a lot of zero output transactions in order to increase the size of that block in bytes. If a block is considered valid, a full node will broadcast that block. This makes it difficult/impossible for nodes without enough bandwidth and storage to continue processing the blockchain.

Also, the time to verify the block hash (two rounds of SHA256) increases, I believe linearly, with the input size. But, network latency will be of more concern and, of course, you can't verify a block unless you download it first.